# Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS Wifi Problem

Tags: wireless, internet

I installed Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS on my Thinkpad T60 laptop. Laptop detected my home wifi and I connected to it. Accidentally, the power plug of router got disconnected from the socket and my laptop got disconnected from internet. Surprisingly, when I reconnected the router to power source, the laptop did not list my home wifi in the available wifi networks. Ubuntu showed all available wifi networks except my home wifi. I connected LAN cable and internet worked fine.

I searched various Ubuntu forums on internet for a solution but I could not find any solution to this problem. So I tried reinstalling Ubuntu 14.04.1. After installation, ubuntu detected my home wifi. I tested the problem scenario again by unplugging the power plug of router. Then the same problem repeated.

Please help with a solution for this problem. I will not be able to reinstall Ubuntu every time this problem repeats.

Thanks in advance...

lspci -nn | grep 0280 command in terminal gave following output:

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection [8086:4227] (rev 02)

Regards,
Srinivas

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of the wireless device from the terminal: lspci -nn | grep 0280 Welcome to askubuntu!

Comment: Thank you @chili555 , I have edited the question to add the output from terminal.

Answer (score 0):

First, check to see if the interface sees your home network by scanning:

```
sudo iwlist wlan0 scan
```

Second, this card does not do N speeds. If your router defaulted to N only, this card may not list it as available in the Network Manager icon. Please check the router. I recommend auto B, G and N. https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBFbn.png

What channel is your router set to? If 12, 13 or 14, some regulatory domains only allow channels 1 through 11. Check your regulatory domain:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit.

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Finally, I suggest you click the Network Manager icon, select Edit Connections and delete your current connection. Force NM to start fresh.

Comment: Hi,Thank you for your detailed reply. I was away on vacation for few days and hence could not reply earlier. I came back home after vacation and switched on the laptop and to my surprise the laptop detected my home wifi without having to do anything code changes. I am sure the problem will arise soon and I will try to implement the steps mentioned in your above reply. Thanks again for your help.